# Sinon.restore not working for stubbing and testing AWS functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, testing, aws-sdk, sinon

So I'm trying to write a few tests for testing an AWS wrapper library that I have been writing.
The tests are running individually without any issues, but won't all run as one 'describe' block.

```
const AWS_REGION = 'eu-west-2';

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
chai.use(sinonChai);

// These help:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243647/sinon-stub-in-node-with-aws-sdk
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61516053/sinon-stub-for-lambda-using-promises
describe('SQS Utilities Test', () => {

  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  it('should add to SQS', async () => {
    sinon.stub(aws.config, 'update');

    const sqs = {
      sendMessage: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      promise: sinon.stub()
    };
    sinon.stub(aws, 'SQS').callsFake(() => sqs);

    // these use the above stubbed version of aws
    const AWSUtilities = require('../index').AWSUtilities;
    const awsUtilities = new AWSUtilities(AWS_REGION);
    const response = await awsUtilities.postToSQS('https://example.com', { id: 1}, 'chicken');

    expect(sqs.sendMessage).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  });

  it('should get from SQS', async () => {
    sinon.stub(aws.config, 'update');

    const sqs = {
      receiveMessage: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      promise: sinon.stub()
    };
    sinon.stub(aws, 'SQS').callsFake(() => sqs);

    // these use the above stubbed version of aws
    const AWSUtilities = require('../index').AWSUtilities;
    const awsUtilities = new AWSUtilities(AWS_REGION);

    const response = await awsUtilities.getFromSQS('https://example.com');
    expect(sqs.receiveMessage).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  });

...
```

What I noticed, is that in the second test, the error I am getting is `sqs.receiveMessage is not a function`, which means that the second test is using the `sqs` object from the first test (I can further verify this as the error changes if I add `receiveMessage` to the first test `sqs` object).

Is this a bug in sinon restore, or have I written something incorrectly? Here is the whole library: https://github.com/unegma/aws-utilities/blob/main/test/SQSTests.spec.js

Comment: Does this line: https://github.com/unegma/aws-utilities/blob/068e49b1dc7398114e9e7d4235853be5ddbbfedf/lib/AWSUtilities.js#L3 (const sqs) must be defined there? That is the reason sinon unable to restore. You can use rewire for require in every require inside it function; if you do not want to change your AWSUtilities implementation.

Comment: seems like it is because you stub different aws package in the test file vs inside the index file. Could you post your index / AWSUtilities file here?

Comment: Can you post the code under test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with Sinon. This an issue of how you are stubbing AWS SDK. Let's break down what's happening within the code you have shared.

```js
const sqs = {
  sendMessage: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
  promise: sinon.stub()
};
sinon.stub(aws, 'SQS').callsFake(() => sqs);

// these use the above stubbed version of aws
const AWSUtilities = require('../index').AWSUtilities;
```

This code does the following

1. Stub `SQS` of `aws`.
2. Load `AWSUtilities.js` (based on the source code in github)

`AWSUtilities.js` does the following as soon as its loaded

```js
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const sqs = new aws.SQS();

// code removed to demo the concept
```

The above code creates an internal `sqs` object, which in this case is made using the stubbed aws module. In node once a module is loaded using `require` it's cached in memory i.e the above code executes only once.

So when the first `it()` executes it in turn loads `AWSUtilities.js` for the first time and is cached. Any subsequent calls gets the cached version. When you call `sinon.restore` it only restores the `SQS` function of `aws` module it doesn't restore the `sqs` object that was created within `AWSUtilities.js`.

I hope that explains the reason for the behavior that you are seeing.

There are multiple ways to fix this issue. Dependency injection, using modules like proxyquire, rewire, stubbing aws from a central location before all test cases etc.

The following is an option to fix it in just the test cases shown here.

```js
describe('SQS Utilities Test', () => {
  let AWSUtilities, sqsStub;

  before(() => {
    sinon.stub(aws.config, 'update');

    sqsStub = {
      sendMessage: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      receiveMessage: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      promise: sinon.stub()
    };
    sinon.stub(aws, 'SQS').callsFake(() => sqs);
    AWSUtilities = require('../index').AWSUtilities;
  });

  after(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  it('should add to SQS', async () => {
    const awsUtilities = new AWSUtilities(AWS_REGION);
    const response = await awsUtilities.postToSQS('https://example.com', { id: 1}, 'chicken');
    expect(sqsStub.sendMessage).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  });

  it('should get from SQS', async () => {
    const awsUtilities = new AWSUtilities(AWS_REGION);
    const response = await awsUtilities.getFromSQS('https://example.com');
    expect(sqsStub.receiveMessage).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your very thorough answer, I really appreciate that, I didn't realise that was how it works under the hood. The reason I wanted to add the sqsStub itself to the `it('should'` functions, was so that I could create unique behaviour (such as different return values) for the `returnsThis` statements for each of the stubbed functions (e.g. `sendMessage`). Looks like I'll have to find a better way to do that, I'll try something like `sqsStub = { ...sqsStub, sendMessage: ...returns...}` and see what happens. Thanks again!